# How to debug c files in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am working on ndk project and it implemented using older `ndk-build` which relies on `Android.mk` and Application.mk and now i have problem when its debugging files, I want to debug those C-files and I googled and tried all suggestion which I found. But use of it.it's giving results for new changes but for old. could please help me out this issue that how to debug c files in android studio.

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
               // cppFlags ""
                version "3.81"
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid, that, I don't understand the problem here? Do you not know how to debug C files in Android Studio or gradle is making release binaries, not debug ones?